# Место аутентификации в многослойной архитектуре

Tags: c#, архитектура, аутентификация

**Введение:**

В системе осуществляется регистрация пользователей.

Каждый пользователь может регистрировать определенные объекты (например, книги. Что именно - не так важно) и менять их параметры.

**Архитектура системы:**

В системе 3 уровня:

1. **Инфраструктурный** - абстракция вокруг методов работы с базой данных
2. **Доменная модель** - бизнес логика, в которой, в частности, определен
   набор возможных действий для каждого типа пользователей (от обычных
   до администратора)
3. **Прикладной** - обертка вокруг доменной модели. Абстрагирует от деталей
   реализации доменной модели.

**Ситуация:**

Только пользователь или администратор может менять параметры учетной записи. Соответственно, чтобы пользователь поменял параметры учетной записи, необходим его пароль (в отличии от администратора).

**Вопрос:**

Авторизацию (полномочия пользователей в зависимости от их статуса) можно определить в  доменной модели.

Но на каком уровне системы производить аутентификацию пользователей?

**P. S.** С моей точки зрения, проводить аутентификацию на прикладном уровне немного странно. Неужели в каждый метод добавлять помимо id пользователя еще и пароль?

**P. P. S.** В своих разработках использую .Net Framework + C#

Comment: Пароль и id передавать совершенно не нужно. У вас должен быть сервис, который управляет объектом типа User. Если такой объект отсутствует, то считаем, что пользователь не представился. А пользователь может строится на основании логина и пароля, сессии, печенек

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ) Только мне не совсем понятно про отсутствие необходимости передавать id. Как же мне тогда пользователя находить в базе данных?)

Comment: Хорошим тоном является после аудентификации пользователя выдавать ему билет (token). Вот этот билет пользователь и будет передавать на сервер, чтобы идентифицировать себя.

Comment: Ага. Получается, мне необходимо в базе данных создать дополнительную таблицу, где Id пользователя будет соответствовать token (сгенерированный код), действующий на время сессии. По этому token'у я нахожу id пользователя для дальнейших манипуляций?

Comment: Если на вебе, то можно ASP.NET Identity

Comment: Не обязательно на время сессии. Токен клиент может хранить в печеньках. Но токен должен иметь время жизни. Можете посмотреть ещё JWT, но тут есть некоторые минусы (нельзя отозвать). Может вам они не страшны

Comment: Буду признательны, если просветите насчет печенек) Не понимаю это слово в данном контексте)

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, но я слышал, что данный подход устарел.

Comment: @Eladei, что-то комментарии поломались. Это всего лишь один из вариантов.

Comment: Grundy, я правильно понимаю, что на прикладном уровне я не провожу никакой авторизации? Она идет поверх прикладного уровня?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если вы используете ASP.NET Core, то алгоритм там следующий, при логине пользователя, на уровне контроллера вы принимаете логин и пароль, получаете пользователя и проверяете его пароль, после чего генерируете токен. В токене будут зашиты привилегии пользователя, все дальнейшие запросы от авторизованного пользователя должны снабжаться токеном. А проверка на доступ к тому или иному action-у или контроллеру уже будет происходить на уровне http-контекста, по сути в методе `Configure()` класса `Startup`. Чтобы разграничивать доступ, вам по сути нужно будет только указать нужному контроллеру или action-ам контроллера атрибуты привилегий доступа. Самый лучший пример по Jwt аутентификации для ASP.NET Core + Angular можно посмотреть в этом [блоге](https://fullstackmark.com/post/10/user-authentication-with-angular-and-asp-net-core). Код примера доступен на [GitHub](https://github.com/mmacneil/AngularASPNETCoreAuthentication).

Пример контроллера, доступного только с политикой `"ApiUser"`

```
[Authorize(Policy = "ApiUser")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DashboardController : Controller
{       
   public DashboardController()
   {

   }

   [HttpGet("home")]
   public IActionResult GetHome()
   {
       return new OkObjectResult(new { Message = "This is secure data!" });
   }
}
```

По есть по сути для конкретного контроллера в зависимости от привилегий пользователя вы можете, либо выполнять некоторые действия, либо производить редирект на страницу ввода пароля.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ. Данный подход удобен в монолитном приложении. А как лучше поступить в случае микросервисной архитектуры?

Comment: Если вы рассмотрите данный блог более подробно, то обнаружите в appsettings.json для "JwtIssuerOptions" такую строчку  "Audience": "http://localhost:5000/" то есть все что там написано, это по сути сервис авторизации, в остальных сервисах вы можете просто в Startup указать использование вашего сервиса авторизации (в Configure() app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication).

Comment: Понятно. Скажите, пожалуйста, я правильно понял, что в рамках представленой в вопросе архитектуре, аутентификация и авторизация располагаются выше прикладного уровня? То есть в рамках данного варианта реализации методы прикладного уровня сами по себе не защищены. (То есть если я захочу просто задействовать их в консольном приложении, то нужен другой подход.) Но в данном случае доступ к ним регулируется из контроллеров.
И насколько данная реализация применима к asp.net mvc 5?

Comment: В вашем консольном приложении приложении просто должна присутствовать обработка jwt при работе с http, в asp.net core просто уже есть готовая библиотека для работы с ними. Но наверняка есть и другие фреймворки и библиотеки. Тут вопрос скорее в том что является ли приложение http или не является. По поводу ASP.NET MVC 5 не могу точно сказать, есть ли для него реализация работы с JWT. Если есть, то применима

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо за подробное объяснение.